# EF6 auto created Stored Procedures for CRUD

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

**Sorry long explanation but short question. For question you can directy look to 2 bold styled text  except this.**

I created my first EF6 CODE FIRST project to learn new features. I tried to implement new stored procedure based CRUD operations.

One of models entity for demonstration for here like this:

```
public partial class POCO
{
    //identy
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // SQL Server Timestamp
    // this.Property(t => t.RowVersion).IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(8).IsRowVersion();
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public int MiscPropery { get; set; }    
}
```

This entity uses SQL server's RowVersion as concurency token, which is "Database Generated Concurency" of course.

First: I created releted stored procedures on my own. I fallowed the EF6 documentation [Stored Procedure Mapping](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Insert/Update/Delete%20Stored%20Procedure%20Mapping)

Then: EntityFramework 6 created database and stored procedures.

```
EntityFramework 6 created insert stored procedure:

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[POCO_Update]
    @ID [int],
    @RowVersion_Original [rowversion],
    @MiscPropery  [int]
    --                  ------- I hope here: @RowsAffected int OUTPUT 

AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[POCOs]
    SET [MiscPropery] = @MiscPropery  
    WHERE (([ID] = @ID) AND (([RowVersion] = @RowVersion_Original) 
            OR ([RowVersion] IS NULL AND @RowVersion_Original IS NULL)))

    SELECT t0.[RowVersion], t0.[FaturaNo]
    FROM [dbo].[POCOs] AS t0
    WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND t0.[ID] = @ID
END


EntityFramework 6 created delete stored procedure:

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[POCO_Delete]
    @ID [int],
    @RowVersion_Original [rowversion]
    --                   ------- I hope here: @RowsAffected int OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE [dbo].[POCOs]
    WHERE (([ID] = @ID) AND (([RowVersion] = @RowVersion_Original) 
          OR ([RowVersion] IS NULL AND @RowVersion_Original IS NULL)))
END
```

My problems came at this point:

IN EntityFramework 6 documentation page, in "Concurrency Tokens" section says: (http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Insert%2fUpdate%2fDelete%20Stored%20Procedure%20Mapping)

Concurrency Tokens

- Update and delete stored procedures may also need to deal with concurrency:
- **If the entity contains any concurrency tokens, the stored procedure should have an *output parameter named RowsAffected* that returns the number of rows updated/deleted.**

And gives these samples on that documentation page:

```
// from documentation page
public class Person
{
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [Timestamp]
  public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Person_Update] 
  @PersonId int, 
  @Name nvarchar(max), 
  @Timestamp_Original rowversion, 
  @RowsAffected int OUTPUT      -- ====> !!!!!
AS 
BEGIN
  UPDATE [dbo].[People]
  SET [Name] = @Name   
  WHERE PersonId = @PersonId AND [Timestamp] = @Timestamp_Original   

  SET @RowsAffected = @@RowCount 
END
```

**But there is no output parameter named RowsAffected in stored procedures created by EF6. 
Im a have to change autocreated stored procedures to follow documantation, or documentation is broken? Or everything goes under the curtains.**